# How can I manage css and php gd2 font size?

Tags: css, image-processing, php-gd

Font size of *php* `gd2` and *css* is different.

How can I manage it?
Any formula to manage it?

Because when I send a `string` with font size in *css* it prints much larger in *php* `gd2` than *css* font.

Please tell me some ideas to manage it.

Comment: Which function are you using? `imagettftext` or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in different versions of php_GD there different types of fonts. if you are using php-gd2 font type is used pt (point) not px. and in first php-gd i think px is font unit.